# Control+Click freeze in Delphi XE

Tags: delphi, ide

I've just reinstalled a new machine and a new Delphi XE on it, Delphi XE's control+click IDE feature (to navigate to the declaration of whatever you control+click on) is freezing, on the previous machine, it used to work okay.

Looking at activity through Process Monitor, the BDS.exe process is opening and reading the same DCUs over and over again, and seems stuck in an infinite loop. BDS.exe is also using 100% of the CPU core it's running on.

Note that this only seems to happen for Control+Click, when compiling or building, everything happens at high speed, and without errors (as far as automated and manual tests of the compiled executable go).

Any clues? I've tried with Andy's IDEFixPack, the issue happens with and without it.

UPDATE: through trial and error, it appears that the "refactoride" BPL (which handles refactoring in the IDE) is at fault, when this package is removed the freeze no longer occurs, and Ctrl+Click works again... but refactorings are entirely gone from the IDE...

Comment: Yes, I've just had this happen yesterday and today. I've had to kill XE and restart it to clear it. I've taken out DDevExtensions and IDE fix pack but left GExperts and so far it's not reappeared. I'm not convinced that its the tools at fault yet though.

Comment: When hovering over an item in the editor, I often get the hint window appearing and disappearing causing a mad flickering that would drive anyone up the wall. Moving the mouse away from any item stops it. While not the same, it does sound related as this behaviour also seems related to some loop it only gets out of when you move the mouse.

Comment: When you remove refactoride, you sometimes also clear up a bug where popping down the Edit menu takes 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDE bug, reported to Embarcadero.

Comment: Have you got a QC for this ? I'm getting the exact same thing in XE3 update 2. Usually while the app is running, if I CTRL-CLICK on a keyword in the code, it will hang up Delphi and bds.exe runs in an infinite loop with it's memory rising and falling.

Comment: The problem still exists in XE7 and happens regularly. I was just waiting like 2min after ctrl+clicking on a function. I'm so fed with that Delphi IDE. It is incredibly slow at every occasion, it really drives me mad. And it gets worse with every release. Unfortunately I have to work with stupid Delphi since years ago we decided to use it as our main development environment for our software. :(